# Display Number of Content Items in Taxonomy Item in TaxonomyItem Shape

Tags: c#, orchardcms, shapes, taxonomy

I'm trying to display a List of my taxonomies with a count of content items in it.

But i can't find out how to do it.
i tried to modify TaxonomyItem.cshtml

```
var terms = (IEnumerable<Orchard.Taxonomies.Models.TermPart>)Model.Taxonomy.TaxonomyPart.Terms;
```

@terms.Count()

but this gives my only the count of taxonomy items, not the count of content items inside each taxonomy.

how can i display this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Each term has the Count of ContentItems, is the Count value of TermPart.Count. Every time a content item is tagged with the term the TermsPartHandler refresh the count.

The TaxonomyItem template uses DisplayChildren, and for each Term it will render the template TaxonomyItemLink.

```
@*
   This shape is displayed for a TermPart when in a Taxonomy details page.

   Alternates:
   - TaxonomyItemLink__[HtmlClassifiedTaxonomyName]
   - TaxonomyItemLink__[HtmlClassifiedTaxonomyName]__[HtmlClassifiedTermName]
*@
@using Orchard.Taxonomies.Models
@{
   TermPart part = Model.ContentPart;
}

<span> This is the number of content items with this Term @part.Count </span>   

@Html.ItemDisplayLink(part)
```

That is the count of items for that Term, not the Taxonomy.

Comment: Is it really that complicated? for expample, you can make a taxonomy link item in the navigation, and there is an option to show the count of content items of the taxonomy...how does it work there?

Answer (score 1):

Simply resolve taxonomy service from TaxonomyItemLink.cshtml

```
var _taxonomyService = WorkContext.Resolve<Orchard.Taxonomies.Services.ITaxonomyService>();
```

And then for each terms from a taxonomy just count the ContentItems

```
@{
  var NumberOfContentItems = _taxonomyService.GetContentItems(part).Count(); 

}
```